# Why is fulltextsearch for phrase ignored in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am executing the following SQL statement on an indexed SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

```
SELECT * FROM mydatabase WHERE (CONTAINS(ColumnA,'"The Apple is red"'))
```

The problem is that it returns too many entries. It also returns entries where 'ColumnA' contains only one of the words ('Apple' or 'is' or 'red'...) and not only the entries which contains the exact phrase.

According to MSDN this should be the way to search for a phrase.

Thanks
cpt.oneeye

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this(Remove the `double quotes ""`):-

```
SELECT * FROM mydatabase WHERE (CONTAINS(ColumnA,'The Apple is red'))
```

The similar issue was there at [MSDN site example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Comment: When i remove the double quotes i get an error message like this: Syntax error near the word 'Apple' in the condition 'The Apple is red'. It seems like whitespaces are not allowed.

Comment: @cpt.oneeye:- Sorry but I didnt get that very well. White spaces are allowed. You may try this also:- Select * FROM mydatabase WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%The Apple is red%'

Comment: I don't want to use LIKE. The duration of such a query is one minute and more.

Comment: Then probably CONTAINS is the best option. But I am not sure why it is not working for you. It works well for me!

Comment: @cpt.oneeye:- Try this:- SELECT * FROM mydatabase WHERE CONTAINS(ColumnA,'"The Apple is red"') What does this show?

Comment: @cpt.oneeye:- Ok I got it. The query is working correctly. Its just that it is not returning what you want. And the reason is:- `CONTAINS:- Searches for precise or fuzzy (less precise) matches to single words and phrases, words within a certain distance of one another, or weighted matches. CONTAINS is a predicate used in the WHERE clause of a Transact-SQL SELECT statement to perform SQL Server full-text search on full-text indexed columns containing character-based data types.` Check MSDN:- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

Comment: It seems like the Fulltext-Index-Catalog ignores several words. For example it skips in this example the words 'The', 'is' and 'red' and just searches for 'Apple'. Then too much entries are shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mydatabase WHERE ColumnA = 'The Apple is red'
```

or

```
Select * FROM mydatabase WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%The Apple is red%'
```

The % says that there might be something different before or after the expression. If that is not the case or you dont want these to be selected, you can use the first one.

Comment: Searching with LIKE-Keyword will need too much time. There are about half a million entries in the database.